Getting SnowflakeSQLException maximum number of expressions in a list exceeded, expected at most 200,000, got 265,633 in IN clause query in snowflake
Here's the select query:
select count(id) AS count,attributes['abc'] from test_schema.transactions_test  where ( id  IN  ('324', '35462', '33546' , .........,'265633') ORDER BY count DESC limit 5000 offset 0
Note : Assume that the id’s in IN clause are dynamic and query generated i.e.265633 distinct id's in IN clause.
Above query getting this error  :
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 76
maximum number of expressions in a list exceeded, expected at most 200,000, got 265,633
Has Snowflake has any issues on :
Limit for number of values/expressions allowed in IN clause ?
How many number of values/expressions allowed in IN clause
Limited size of snowflake query statement ?
I assume above snowflake query should return count but got the maximum number of expressions in a list exceeded exception.
From the error logs it might exceeded number of values/expressions in IN clause.
Is snowflake has any limit on number of values/expressions allowed in IN clause.
Could anyone please suggest any suggestions ?

Consider placing these id values into a separate bona-fide table, and then joining to that table:
CREATE TABLE test_schema.ids (id varchar(55));
INSERT INTO test_schema.ids (id)
VALUES
    ('324'),
    ('35462'),
    ...
    ('265633');

SELECT COUNT(id) AS count, attributes['abc']
FROM test_schema.transactions_test t1
INNER JOIN test_schema.ids t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 0;


Thanks Mr. Tim Biegeleisen for the quick reply. Do you have more idea why and how this error occurred.Is there any  limit for number of values/expressions allowed in IN clause in snowflake. Does snowflake has any settings for change this.

@KavitaShinde expected at most 200,000 ... to be honest, I'm surprised that Snowflake even accepts this many values in an IN(...) clause.  It is really bad coding practice to be hard coding so many values this way.  My answer provides one possible workaround for you.

Thanks Mr. Tim Biegeleisen for the help.I will work on the workaround you gave.

Most databases have a limit to the length of a valid SQL query. For better performance and ease of maintenance, the lookup table approach will be a better choice as Tims suggests.
